# Question from Renmart: For any polynomial $p(z)$, any $c \in \mathbb{C}$, $r \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$

Tags: complex-analysis

This is a question from Reinhold Remmert: Theory of Complex Functions page 184.

For any polynomial $p(z) $, any $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$, $r \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$, we have $$\int_{dB(0,r)}\overline{p(z+z_0)}dz = 2\pi ir^{2}\overline{p^{'}(z_0)}$$

For a start, I can only write $\overline{p(z+z_0)}$ in terms of the power series below:$$a_0+a_1\overline{(z+z_0)}+a_2\overline{(z+z_0)^2}+...+a_n\overline{(z+z_0)^n}$$

However I cannot apply the term by term integration as $\overline{p}$ may not be a series of continuous functions converging uniformly. If this cant be used, how should I approach this question?

Comment: What do you mean?  $p$ is a polynomial, so the series has only finitely many terms.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Sorry I missed out one thing, edited.

Comment: You probably mean [Reinhold **Remmert**](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinhold_Remmert)

Comment: Is $c=z_0$? Or what is $z_0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not correct as it is written. For an example, choose $p(z)=z^2$, $z_0=1$. Then $p(z+z_0)=(z+1)^2$ and $p'(1)=2$ so $2\pi i r^2 \overline{p'(z_0)} = 4\pi i r^2$. However, 
$$
\int_{\partial B(1,r)} \overline{(1+z)^2}\, dz = \int_0^{2\pi} (1+1+re^{-i\theta})^2 ire^{i\theta} \, d\theta = \int_0^{2\pi} 4r^2 i \, d\theta = 8 \pi i r^2.
$$

What is correct is instead that 
$$
\int_{\partial B(z_0,r)} \overline{f(z)} \, dz = 2\pi i r^2 \overline{f'(z_0)}. 
$$
(Incidentally, my German edition of Remmert's book has this claim, not yours).

To prove this, write $f(z)=\sum b_k (z-z_0)^k$ so $\overline{f(z)}= \sum \overline{b_k} (\overline{z-z_0})^k$. Now use that on $\partial B(z_0,r)$, we have $\overline{z-z_0}=\frac{r^2}{z-z_0}$. Can you continue from there?

Comment: @ I can fix the problem of your counter example by setting our problem to only integrating over the path $dB(0,r)$. I think my department took the question but modified one small part.